# How to decode the company number in the field `header$companynumb`

Tags: api, openfda, uses-of-open-data

Is there a lookup table where I can find the names of repackaging or drug manufacturing companies with companynumb reported in the field companynumb?

e.g. "companynumb": "200501050"

Answer (score 1):

According to the field-by-field reference page for the drug events API, "companynumb" is a self-assigned identifier. And I don't know of any lookup table that would enable you to decode a "companynumb".

In some cases, "companynumb" includes the name of company, but not in all cases.

See for example: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?count=companynumb.exact

Comment: Is the `Self assigned identifier` number generated by the FAERS database (Similar to unique key) or companies assigns themselves? If companies assigns the number to themselves, is this number the same for different reports?

Comment: I think the phrase `self assigned identifier` is ambiguous.

Comment: I am interested in identifying companies submitting the ADR reports, is this possible?

Comment: @Eliford - It should be possible in most cases to identify company submitting a given report.  Here’s a paraphrase of the guidance (from [link](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/xml/icsr-xml-v2.1.dtd) to companies re: ‘companynumb’. 

Company should list (1) identification of country of primary source, (2) list Sender Identifier, Sender Organization, and (3) the company international case report number, delimited by hyphens. For example, report transmitted by US company to regulatory authority would populate ** "US-Company Name-12345" **, where "12345" is company's unique case report number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer. It has helped me understand the company numbers. It seems, for some reports, company numbers miss both (1) country of primary source, and (2) Sender Organization.